# How to include mapnik lib in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7 now in want mapnik to be included in python. I have use exe file to include other library file like GDAL, and other. But for Mapnik can any one suggest me any exe like that so it can be easy or library file but how to install it, as i found many help not usefulness. PLEASE  any one help me out in this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can get mapnik here: http://mapnik.org/download/.  There is also a windows binary available available here: http://mapnik.org/news/2011/11/29/windows-binaries-progress/.

Then simply follow your platform's [instalation guide](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Mapnik-Installation).

Once installed correctly you can import it to Python in the normal way.

Comment: i have went though this link and i want but not able to get.i want some thing like exe that can directly execute or other library installation in python.

Comment: I don't understand what more you need.  If you read the documentation and follow the instructions you should be able to call Mapnik from Python.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Its not working. Can you tell me other way out.

Comment: You need to give a more information.  What versions of python and Mapnik are you using?  What is the error message you are getting.  It is very difficult to make any suggestion without an adaquate description of the problem.

Comment: Python 2.7 and mapnik2-2.0.1. i am coping placing mapnik folder of python in C:/python2.7/Lib/site_pakages. Is it correct or else some other way? I am unable to get this lib feature in my sample code. Can u help me out.